# ¿Cómo habilito un campo Text Box si el usuario selecciona un Radio Button de varios que tengo en ASP.NET C#?

Tags: html, c#, asp.net, radiobutton

De ante mano mil gracias por su apoyo! tengo un formulario en **ASP.NET** para un modulo en un gestor de contenido llamado **DNN** en donde le pido al usuario que seleccione que tipo de empresa tiene, le dispongo de un `<asp:RadioButtonList>` con 4 items que son:
° Privada
° Oficial
° Mixta
° Otra
dispongo de un campo `<asp:TextBox>` que se encuentra inhabilitado, si el usuario escoge la opcion de: **°Otra**, quiero que se habilite el campo `<asp:TextBox>` para que me diga que otro tipo de empresa tiene.

**Ejemplo de View.ascx:**

```
<div>
   <asp:RadioButtonList ID="T_Empresa" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="MRadio" Style="margin-left: 1rem">
       <asp:ListItem Value="Privada">Privada</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="Oficial">Oficial</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="Mixta">Mixta</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem ID="btnRadioOtra" Value="Otra">Otra</asp:ListItem>
   </asp:RadioButtonList>
</div>
<div>
   <asp:TextBox ID="OtraEmpresa" runat="server" Width="100" placeholder="Cuál?" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

Lo intenté con `JavaScript` pero no fue posible!
Lo intenté con el `CodeBehind` pero no puedo agregarle un evento al `<asp:RadioButtonList>` porque no lo aguanta y me arroja error al ejecutarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar las siguientes líneas:

```
string valor = T_Empresa.SelectedValue.ToString();
if (valor.Equals("Otra"))
    OtraEmpresa.enabled = true;
```

Con eso, estaría funcionando.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu interés, eso debería agregarlo a un script? es que ya intente agregar funciones de JavaScript pero no me funciona por que el ítem del radiobutton **Otra ** no me deja aplicarle esos métodos, no funcionan!

Comment: No, esto lo debes hacer en C#, en tu code behind a nivel de servidor. No por javascript. Puedes hacer en el evento SElectedIndexChanged. Pruebalo y nos cuentas.

Answer (score 0):

En respuesta a **Chistian Amado.** mil gracias por tu ayuda, realmente me oriento bastante y logre dar solución a mi pregunta con tu respuesta por medio del **Code Behind** en **C#** de esta manera:

```
protected void btnEmpresa(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (btnRadioOtra.Selected == true)
        {
            OtraEmpresa.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            OtraEmpresa.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```